# GWT/appEngine RPC serialization

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

Up until last week I have been running my GWT/AppEngine app with no problems using java.io.Serializable and implements Serializable on my classes in RPC calls.

Now I get this error on appengine: Type 'com.foobar.web.shared.RPCDTOclass' was not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable' and did not have a custom field serializer.

I still have the implements Serializable.  If I fix/change that class and make it com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable it works for that class but I get the same error for other classes used in RPC.  I only have Strings in some of them, so it isn't that I have types that I can't serialize.

I don't see anyone else having this problem so I must have made some type of change that is causing it, but I don't know what.  The error shows up on AppEngine, so I think it must be an appengine problem?

Thanks

Adding an example

```
public class UserLogInDTO implements IsSerializable {

private String Email;
private String PasswordHash;

public UserLogInDTO(){}

public UserLogInDTO(String email, String passwordhash){
    setEmail(email);
    setPasswordHash(passwordhash);
}
public void Set(String email, String passwordhash){
    this.setEmail(email);
    this.setPasswordHash(passwordhash);
}
/**
 * @return the email
 */
public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}
/**
 * @param email the email to set
 */
public void setEmail(String email) {
    Email = email.toLowerCase();
}
/**
 * @return the passwordHash
 */
public String getPasswordHash() {
    return PasswordHash;
}
/**
 * @param passwordHash the passwordHash to set
 */
public void setPasswordHash(String passwordHash) {
    PasswordHash = passwordHash;
}
```

}

If I have implements IsSerializable it works, if implements Serializable  it used to work but now doesn't.  I am using 1.7.2 SDK for AppEngine 2.4.0 for GWT

Comment: Are the RPC serialization policies correctly deployed? Have you set the caching up correctly to ensure you're running the up to date version of the app.?

Comment: What do you mean RPC serialization policies correctly deployed?  I just double checked and there is only one version of the app.  I deployed an up to date version of the app as well to make sure it is as expected.

Comment: Did you upgrade to new App Engine SDK? Maybe you can post an example of a class for which you get this error.

Comment: @Michael: I mean the `*.gwt.rpc` files generated by the GWT compilation. And by _up to date version_ I meant that your browser correctly loads the app from the server rather than use a previous version from the cache. See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#perfect_caching